# How to make a bar for open tabs like as AdminLTE template

Tags: uitableview, tabs

[image]How to make a bar for open tabs like as AdminLTE template html css js or jq ?
When I open a tab from the sidebar, it appears in the top bar, and I can return to it later or close it and I don't know the correct name for it and whether it can be done with javascript or jquery

Photo attached